# installing open CV in 18.04 LTS

Tags: opencv

I'm getting the following error when I run: make -j $(($(nproc) + 1))

```
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Please post the **entire** output of the command,

Comment: have you tried this install guide : https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/ also could you bemore specific? what flavor and version number of opencv are you trying to install?